changing agents' speed in GIS
I want to create a population of clients to be served in random points on a map using GIS. I divided my map in towns which really exist.
The event chooses a town through a custom distribution and then places the client in a random point inside the town. I have a fleet of trucks to serve my clients..
After the creation of the client I send the nearest truck to the client to serve him and then the truck return in his base.
I would like to change the speed of my trucks depending on the route which they have. For example I want to set 30 km/h if the truck has to go in urban roads, I want to set 90 km/h if the truck has to go in high speed roads and I want to set 50 km/h if the truck has to go in low speed roads like in  mountain areas.
I move my truck on the GISmap with the function moveTo() after select it with getNearestagentByRoute().
I already set the speed depending on the distance between the truck and the client but this does not consider the type of the road.
AnyLogic can recognise the type of the route which the truck has?


AnyLogic can recognise the type of the route which the truck has?

No. AnyLogic does not even "know" this, it is a web-service that provides route info, AnyLogic just forwards that to your agents (if you use the default setup).
Either you use your own shapefile (with full control over road types) or you sign up to your own route provider (but that typically costs money). Both are not trivial to sort out.
Else, you can define your own GIS areas and adjust speeds that way.
